# Webpack compile file to S3 or CDN Server

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, amazon-cloudfront

i'm working on React Project Javascript universal (Express.js as server)
in the production build, i'm using webpack and babel as a bundling and transpiler.

Everything work fine,

However, i'm thinking that, those bundles are actually just static javascript, styles and html.

Can we upload it to Amazon S3 and link it with Cloudfront and make these files available over CDN?

I try googling searching for webpack and CDN but didn't find any useful information.

Or did i misunderstand something? Will it work like what i think? And can we automate this using just webpack cli ?

Please advise,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack is mostly concerned about the building (and bundling) of your assets. What you do with them/where you host them is up to you, and you might want to look into some kind of CI process/tool to manage automated deployments for you, once the bundles are built. Webpack doesn't (afaik) handle deployment.

Comment: Alright, but didn't webpack also add `<script src />` in `index.html` file? and it's currently add local relative path, not CDN path. So, do i have to config anything on webpack to `src` them to CDN path?

Comment: Webpack doesn't necessarily add a script tag for you, unless you are using this plugin: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin in which case it looks like there is a means to override the default template with your own.

Comment: Done, i integrate with cloudfront and it's supereasy. I don't even need to upload JS to s3.